# Javascript ES6 console.log object using template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have simple object that I want to display in console

```
var obj = { name: 'John', age: 22 }
```

If I type:

```
console.log(obj)
```

Object { name: "John", age: 22 }

If I type:

```
console.log('my object is: ' + obj)
```

my object is: [object Object]

```
console.log('my object is: %o', obj)
```

my object is:  Object { name: "John", age: 22 }

## How can I achieve this using a template literal?

If I type:

```
console.log(`my object is: ${obj}`)
```

my object is: [object Object]

Comment: Can also just do: `console.log('my object is: ', obj);`.  Templates themselves are not smart about making a string representation of an object so you can't get the desired output purely from a template literal.  They just invoke the default string conversion which is not what you want here.  You will have to make the desired string representation yourself and pass that to the literal.

Comment: Above is the correct answer … you have to go back to the old way of comma separated as template literal, and the literal representation of an object is `[object Object]`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could serialize the object with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
var obj = { name: 'John', age: 22 };
console.log(`my object is: ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
```

Comment: ES6 note: Yes, but notice JSON.stringify returns undefined when working with classes and console.log works pretty similar to the good old toSource().

Answer (score -1):

console.log`My object is: ${obj}`;

There are tildes(`) at both ends of the grayed section, but the formatting is removing them

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```js
var obj = { name: 'John', age: 22 }
log`This is obj: ${obj}`

function log(strings, ...values) {
   console.log(strings.reduce((p, c, i) => 
        `${p}${c}${values[i]?JSON.stringify(values[i]):''}`, ''));
}
```

Comment: such an over-complicated way to perform a simple operation.
accepted answer serves the purpose.